# java 8 time api - Instant.now(clock) vs LocaldateTime.now(clock)

Tags: java, datetime, time, java-8, java.time.instant

For following code for java 8

```
  1. System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemDefaultZone())); 
  2. System.out.println(Instant.now(Clock.systemDefaultZone()));
```

Line 1 print current time by adding offset but line 2 print current time without adding offset.

I checked the source code of both and found that `LocaDateTime.now(clock)` return `clock.instant()` return time by adding offset but `Instant.now(clock)` not doing so.

Why it designed like this? Aren't we expecting same result in both case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE: Instant has nothing to do with UTC in the timezone sense.  It is related to UTC as a time standard only.**

The major difference is the return type.  They have different String representations because the types themselves have very different meanings.

**Instant#now(Clock)** returns **Instant**.  An **Instant** is ["[a]n instantaneous point on the time-line"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

**LocalDate#now(Clock)** returns **LocalDate**.  A **LocalTime** is ["a description of the local time as seen on a wall clock"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html).

As a result **Instant#now(Clock)** and **LocalDate#now(Clock)** mean very different things and naturally have different outcomes.  The major thing they have in common is a name.  Method names are dust.  Refer to the types.

On a fixed **Clock**, both **Instant.now(clock)** and **LocalDate.now(clock)** will return constant values.  The point of accepting **Clock** as a parameter is to be able to control things like the reference time or clock resolution.

Comment: Could you please tell me then what is the need of passing  Clock as a parameter?

Comment: Clock is allowed as a parameter to permit use cases like a fixed or offset clock in testing or different resolutions like seconds or minutes as required. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html

Comment: @nantitv I've rewritten my answer.  It was a bit vague before.  Does it answer your question effectively now?

Comment: Please give me some time to digest the concept